# Table inside another table squashed

Tags: html, css

Am having trouble nesting one table inside another:

[image: Squashed table]

I want the inner tables to span across the entire width of the outer table. Here is the generated HTML:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

<tr><td align="center">4 laptops were not added because they lacked unique identifiers.</td></tr>  <tr><td align="center">2 laptops were not added because they already exist in the database: </td></tr><tr><td>
  <table><th>Hostname</th><th>Asset Tag</th><th>Serial</th>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>4646466</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>4646467</td>
    </tr>
    </table></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="center">2 laptops were added to the database: </td></tr><tr><td>
  <table><th>Hostname</th><th>Asset Tag</th><th>Serial</th>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>4646468</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>4646469</td>
    </tr>
    </table></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look

```html
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" border="1">

<tr><td align="center">4 laptops were not added because they lacked unique identifiers.</td></tr>  <tr><td align="center">2 laptops were not added because they already exist in the database: </td></tr><tr><td>
  <table  border="1" style="width:100%;"><th>Hostname</th><th>Asset Tag</th><th>Serial</th>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>4646466</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>4646467</td>
    </tr>
    </table></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="center">2 laptops were added to the database: </td></tr><tr><td>
  <table><th>Hostname</th><th>Asset Tag</th><th>Serial</th>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>4646468</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>4646469</td>
    </tr>
    </table></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `width` attribute

```
width = '100%'
```

to the inner table. It will make it spread all over the width of the containing cell.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yzfnj350/3/)

Comment: Thankyou this is perfect. I think I have to accept Head In Cloud's answer though as it came first.